# Need help for this shell script for AWS profile switcher using Case

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, shell

I am writing a Shell script to switch AWS profile more easily

```
#!/bin/bash
PROFILES=$(aws configure list-profiles)
arr=($PROFILES)

PS3='Please enter your choice: '
select opt in "${arr[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
         $opt)
            echo "Selecting ${opt}"
            export AWS_PROFILE="${opt}"
            ;;
         "Quit")
            break
            ;;   
         *) echo "invalid option $REPLY";;
    esac
done
```

Everything looks good where I can select my profile from the list. But the problem is I want to select Quit option to exit the program. For example the list is containing of 3 profiles.
Output is

1. Profile 1
2. Profile 2
3. Profile 3

Desired result is when I enter 4, the program will quit, and if I enter 5 or anything else different, it will print out invalid option $REPLY.
Actual result is nothing happen when I enter 4 or anything else.
Thanks all

Comment: From the bash man-page on the `select` command: _The list is executed after each selection until a break command is executed._ Your code does not do a `break` when you detect an invalid option.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should be able to check the input number directly.

```
PROFILES=$(aws configure list-profiles)
arr=($PROFILES)
pronum=$(echo "$PROFILES"|wc -l)
echo -n "choose one>"
read id
if [ $id -ge 1 -a $id -le $pronum ] ; then
  echo "You chose ${arr[$(($id-1))]}"
elif [ $id -eq 4 ] ;  then
  echo "Exit"
else
  echo "$id is invalid"
fi
```

Comment: `pronum=${#PROFILES}` No need for `wc`

Comment: I think you mean `${#arr[*]}`

Comment: If that helps, sure.

Comment: Your solution work well but this is not I desired. I want to use the function Select as in this  topic https://askubuntu.com/questions/1705/how-can-i-create-a-select-menu-in-a-shell-script

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @WeDBA I have created this script to set the AWS_PROFILE variable for my shell interactively.

```bash
# Function to set AWS_PROFILE using fzf
set_aws_profile() {
  local aws_config_file="$HOME/.aws/config"

  # Get all profile names from AWS config file
  profile_names=($(aws configure list-profiles))
  
  # Use fzf for profile selection
  selected_profile=$(printf '%s\n' "${profile_names[@]}" | fzf --prompt="Select AWS Profile: ")
  
  # Set the selected profile to AWS_PROFILE environment variable
  export AWS_PROFILE="$selected_profile"
  
  # Optionally, print the selected profile for verification
  echo "Selected AWS Profile: $AWS_PROFILE"
}
```

put this in your zsh config file. You can try it with bash if you want.

1. In the shell you can call `set_aws_profile` and you will get an interactive fzf selector.
2. Select the profile you want to use and then it will set the AWS_PROFILE env variable for you.